# regex to extract mentions in Twitter

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a regex in python to extract mentions from Tweets.

My attempt:

```
regex=re.compile(r"(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)")
```

It works fine for any mention like @mickey
However, in mentions with underscores like @mickey_mouse, it only extracts @mickey.

How can I modify the regex for it to work in both cases?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you could use `\w` for *word character* which also contains underscore. Something like [`(?<![\w.-])@(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/VBJIdS/2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an underscore to the last set like this:

```
(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IVBuug/1)

On a side note, [Twitter Handle rules](https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299) allow you to have usernames starting with numbers & underscores as well. So to extract twitter handles a regex could be as simple as: `@\w{1,15}` *(allows characters, numbers and underscores and includes the 15 character limit)*. Will need some additional lookaheads/lookbehinds based on where the regex might be used.

Answer (score 0):

A [shorter version](https://regex101.com/r/LhGTHk/1), including the negative cases from @degant:

```regex
(?<=@)\w+
```

Comment: `(?i)` is useless with `\w`, no needs to escape `@`, OP wants to match only alpha just after `@`

Comment: Nice, thanks, so it is possible to make this even shorter.