# Update a regex that matches twitter like mentions to allow for dots

Tags: php, regex

I have already found helpful answers for a regex that matches twitter like username mentions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43958095/6811102) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351873/6811102)

`(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)`

`(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)`

However, I need to update this regex to also include usernames that has dots.

- One or more dots are allowed in a username.
- The username must not start or end with a dot.
- No two consecutive dots are allowed.

Example of a matched string:

```
@valid.user.name
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Examples of non-matched strings:

```
@.user.name // starts with a dot
@user.name. // ends with a dot
@user..name // has two consecutive dots
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))` is a positive lookbehind that requires a match to be at the start of the string or right after an alphanumeric, `-`, `_`, `.`, you may write it in a more compact way as `(?<![\w.-])`, a negative lookbehind.

Next, `([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)` captures 1+ ASCII letters and then 1+ ASCII letters or/and underscores. You seem to make sure the first char is a letter, then any number of sequences of `.` and 1+ word chars are allowed, that is, you may use `[A-Za-z]\w*(?:\.\w+)*`.

As you do not want to match it if there is a `.` right after the expected match, you need to set a lookahead that will require a space or end of string, `(?!\S)`.

So, combining it, you  can use

```
'~(?<![\w.-])@([A-Za-z]\w*(?:\.\w+)*)(?!\S)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NJAXxw/1/)

**Details**

- `(?<![\w.-])` - no letters, digits, `_`, `.` and `-` immediately to the left of the current location are allowed
- `@` - a `@` char
- `([A-Za-z]\w*(?:\.\w+)*)` - Group 1:

  - `[A-Za-z]` - an ASCII letter
  - `\w*` - 0+ letters, digits, `_`
  - `(?:\.\w+)*`  - 0+ sequences of

    - `\.` - dot
    - `\w+` - 1+ letters, digits, `_`
- `(?!\S)` - whitespace or end of string are  required immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this refactored regex:

```
(?<=[^\w.-]|^)@([A-Za-z]+(?:\.\w+)*)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RXca30/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=[^\w.-]|^)`: Lookbehind to assert that we have start of line or any non-word, non-dot, non-hyphen character before current position
- `@`: Match literal `@1
- `(`: Start capture group

  - `[A-Za-z]+`: Match 1+ ASCII letters
  - `(?:\.\w+)*`: Match 0 or more instances of dot followed 1+ word characters
- `)`: End capture group
- `$`: End

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Simpler version** (same [result](https://regexr.com/3t43a))

`^@[a-zA-Z](\.?[\w-]+)*$`

**Original**

[Another one](https://regexr.com/3t41t):

`^@[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_-]?(\.?[\w\d-]+){0,}$`

- `^@` starts with @
- `[a-zA-Z]` first char
- `[a-zA-Z_-]?` match `a-zA-Z_-` 0 or more times
- `(` start group

  - `\.?` match `.` (optional)
  - `[\w\d-]+` match `a-zA-Z0-9-_` 1 or more times
- `)` end group
- `{0,}` repeat group 0 to infinite times
- `$` end

**Tests**

valid:

```
@validusername
@valid.user.name
@valid-user-name
@valid_user-name
@valid-user123_name
@a.valid-user123_name
```

not valid:

```
@-invalid.user
@_invalid.user
@1notvalid-user_123name33
@.user.name
@user.name.
@user..name
```